# Is it possible to modify XMLHttpRequest data from beforeSend callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to modify the data sent in an Ajax request by modifying the XMLHttpRequest object in the beforeSend callback?  and if so how might I do that?

Comment: Modify how? What aspects of the call do you want to modify?

Comment: Yes Its Possible. have you tried beforeSend callback yourself ? If yes Whats the Problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can modify it, the signature of [`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is *actually* (in jQuery 1.4+):

```
beforeSend(XMLHttpRequest, settings)
```

even though the documentation has just `beforeSend(XMLHttpRequest)`, [you can see how it's called here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L379), where [`s` is the settings object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L198):

```
if ( s.beforeSend && s.beforeSend.call(s.context, xhr, s) === false ) {
```

So, you *can* modify the `data` argument before then ([note that it's *already* a string by this point](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L207-209), even if you passed in an object).  An example of modifying it would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  beforeSend: function(xhr, s) {
    s.data += "&newProp=newValue";
  }
});
```

If it helps, the same signature applies to the [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) global handler (which *does* have correct [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) showing it), like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(xhr, s) {
  s.data += "&newProp=newValue";
});
```

Comment: +1 to you, but -1 to the out-of-date jQuery docs... removed my answer as it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this solution and wonder why I am not finding the s.data
so I changed the request type to post and it was there,
Looks like if you are using GET request the data property is not there, I guess you have to change the s.url

for get method:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr, s) {
    s.url += "&newProp=newValue";
  }
});
```

for post method:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr, s) {
    s.data += "&newProp=newValue";
  }
});
```