# Hook additional data before $.post() on all calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, hook

I'm having trouble figuring out how to hook in data each time jQuerys `$.post()` method is called.

I have **several** event handlers that obtains values from throughout the page before submitting them to the server via AJAX. An example of such a call is as follows:

```
var data = {
    link_data:{'foo': 'bar', 'foo2' : 'bar2'}
};

$.post('some_url',data,function(returned_data){
    //Do something with returned_data
});
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way of hooking in an additional piece of data that is sent with every `$.post()` request made.

Essentially, what I was hoping for was a way to amend the 'data' parameter that's sent to the server just before submission so that the sent value looks something more like this:

```
{
 token: some_predefined_variable,
 link_data{'foo': 'bar', 'foo2' : 'bar2'}
}
```

Is there a way to hook this in so that I don't have to go and amend every single method where data is being sent to the server by `$.post()`?

Thanks.

**Update:** I found the best solution was actually posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4529949/1489130). Bit annoying that you have to manually set the post data but it works :)

Comment: You can use `$.ajaxSetup()` to set global default options and add a `beforeSend` handler. It might be messy to fool with the post data, but you could as an alternative add a custom request header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$.ajaxSetup()` and `beforeSend`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
        settings.data = {token: some_predefined_variable, link_data : settings.data };
    }
});
```

Comment: Can `some_predefined_data` be a function call?

Comment: @Sinmok I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is, is that at this point `settings.data` is already encoded for delivery by POST. Adding an object like you've suggested breaks it and gets sent as an [Object object]

Comment: It was the closest answer to what I needed. Should I not have accepted it?

Comment: @Sinmok You should not have, it might discourage someone with a better answer from posting.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var data = {
    link_data:{'foo': 'bar', 'foo2' : 'bar2'}
};

data.token = some_predefined_variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {link_data : {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2' : 'bar2'} }
});
```

See this [**link**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm) for a better explanation to how it's done (the above is really all you need).

Comment: If a `$.post()` already has its own value for the "data" property, I don't think this will add the token as desired in the OP.

Comment: `$.post()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax`, so the global data values set in the `$.ajaxSetup` will be sent as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna implement your own function, like

```
function SinmoksPost(userData){
    var x = {
        token: some_predefined_variable,
        data:userData
    }

    $.post('some_url',x,function(returned_data){
        //Do something with returned_data
    });
}
```

and then call `SinmoksPost` instead of `$.post`