# How to serialize form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

On my MVC application datetime on server is set as "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

and On client side client set the date as "mm/dd/yyyy" let say "1/31/2015"
and this date is set in

If client set such date 1/31/2015 the on Client side I receive wrong date and I used following code for do so,Please do the need ful?

Also SaveMerchantData  data model has property binded with view with Textboxfor(startdate)

Please help?

```
$.ajax
({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveMerchantData")',
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#frmTicket").serialize(),
            datatype:"text/html",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Record saved successfully');
                $("#Merchantlist").html(result);
                $("#MerchantName").val('');
                $("#Address").val('');
                $("#ContactNumber").val('');
                $("#Email").val('');
                $("#MerchantId").val();


            }
        });
  public PartialViewResult SaveMerchantData(SaveMerchantData objS)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to get a good reasonable date object to work with.

```
var d = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

You can then output it to the required format using

```
d.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

So all in all you can simply convert the date string using

```
var outString = moment(inString, "MM-DD-YYYY").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

The second part of what you need to do is to modify the string before making the request. You can do this using `$.ajax()`'s `beforeSend` callback, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527054/is-it-possible-to-modify-xmlhttprequest-data-from-beforesend-callback).
This simply means you can't serialize your data right away, you'll need to read in the data, edit the string and then serialize it for the post.